# discord.js: How to fix Unexpected token '??=' Eror

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
// const client = new discord.Client();
// client.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);
```

**output**:

> Unexpected token '??='
> at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
> at Object. (C:\Users\pouya\Desktop\develop\node\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RESTManager.js:5:20)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)

```
 "dependencies": {
     "discord.js": "^13.7.0",
     "dotenv": "^16.0.1"
    }
```

Comment: Update NodeJS to LTS

Comment: the problem may have to do with the client constant, make sure to capitalize `new Discord.Client();`

Comment: im finde update lts to fix probelem

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Update your Node.JS

The error is complaining about a new symbol `??=`, which is only available in Node 14+ (?)